# PowerCLI doesn't wait when piping to select

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with the Select alias.

My script is getting a list of VM's with get-vm where they are powered on, then selecting only the Name value.

If I keep "|select Name" in the cmdlet, the script output is out of order as shown below. When I remove the select, no matter how big the query, it does it in order. Why is this?

Example:

```
Connect-VIServer vcenter

$myvm=Read-Host "Enter the VM name or names using wildcards to update"

write-host "VM's to update: " 
get-vm $myvm | Where-Object {($_.powerstate -eq "PoweredOn")}

write-host "Exiting without action"
```

The results from above return my expected results of my "Test* vm's", then the message "Exiting without action"

```
Enter the VM name or names using wildcards to update: test*
VM's to update: 
Name                 PowerState Num CPUs MemoryGB       
----                 ---------- -------- --------       
TestServer01         PoweredOn  1        4.000          
Test-ServerB         PoweredOn  1        4.000          
Exiting without action
```

However, when I add the select Name usign this code:

```
Connect-VIServer vcenter

$myvm=Read-Host "Enter the VM name or names using wildcards to update"

write-host "VM's to update: " 
get-vm $myvm | Where-Object {($_.powerstate -eq "PoweredOn")} |select Name

write-host "Exiting without action"
```

My results now show the last write-host command BEFORE the vm results.

```
Enter the VM name or names using wildcards to update: test*
VM's to update: 

Exiting without action
Name           
----           
TestServer01
Test-ServerB
```

Comment: The Write-Host stream and the Write-Output stream are two separate streams and are not at all synced to each other. You should not assume that they are.

Comment: Correct, meaning that you need to stream the output to the host with e.g. `... | Format-Table`

Comment: I use write-host for my "text" but are you saying the output from get-vm .... is using write-output? How does it work then when not using select but using Format-table Name instead?

Comment: Format-Table would put the output into the same stream as Write-Host I believe.

Comment: Also, to quote Jeffrey Snover (he created Powershell) "Using Write-Host is almost always wrong'

Comment: @EBGreen Also, using two different kinds of quotes is almost always wrong ;)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician...Bwahaha...I pretty much exclusively use ' because of powershell. I think I made a conscious effort to use " at the beginning then just muscle memory'd the ' at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the conversation! I will refrain from write-host in my script and stick to write-output, then continue to use |select which is working well. I have nixed write-host from my vocabulary. I'll do some follow up reading on the subjects. To sum it up, I changed from write-host to write-ouput and all is well now.